# How do I delete .class files after executing Java file using .batch script?

Tags: java, batch-file

Here is my batch file, which I use to execute Java file stored anywhere in the computer.
Pre-requisite is to put JRE and JDK (or related stuff) in PATH variable

Everytime I execute the java file (by drag and drop upon the script file), JRE creates .class file.
I want the file to get deleted by the same script when I close the execute java file.
How do I do it?

Also how to make the script to auto close cmd window after executing it.

```
@echo off
cd %~f1

javac %~n1.java
java %~n1

timeout 2 >nul

exit
```

Comment: so you are asking how to delete a file on windows from a batch?

Comment: The .class file is the actual executable. Why are you deleting it when it finishes?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/del.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, after my java program gets executed and I close it.
I will put a video later on what issue I'm facing